# Labeled folders in test and train data and sorting the data into them based on label

Tags: excel, vba, machine-learning, dataset, coreml

I'm looking to train a CoreML image classifier and it requires having a folder for each label in the test and training data, and putting the data with that label in the correct folder. I have a folder structure like this:

```
Train
 -1
 -2
 -3
 -4
Test
 -1
 -2
 -3
 -4
```

I already have the test and training data split, but I do not have the data split into classes.

And I have an excel csv file where the beginning looks like this.

[image: first few rows]

With the image names being structured `10_left.jpeg, 10_right.jpeg, 13_left.jpeg`, etc..

There are over 15,000 images, so doing it manually is not the best. Is there some way to move the files into the correct folder based on the label name within vba in excel? Or some other way? Thanks!

Edit:
Based on an answer below, I tried this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim iRow


Sub SaveFilesToFolders()

Dim Folder0 As String, Folder1 As String, Folder2 As String, Folder3 As String, Folder4 As String
Dim FileNameRange As Range
Dim actCell As Range
Dim SelFolder As Integer
Dim ActFileName As String

    Folder0 = "/Volumes/G-DRIVE\ mobile\ USB-C/trainDataInClasses/0"
    Folder1 = "/Volumes/G-DRIVE\ mobile\ USB-C/trainDataInClasses/1"
    Folder2 = "/Volumes/G-DRIVE\ mobile\ USB-C/trainDataInClasses/2"
    Folder3 = "/Volumes/G-DRIVE\ mobile\ USB-C/trainDataInClasses/3"
    Folder4 = "/Volumes/G-DRIVE\ mobile\ USB-C/trainDataInClasses/4"

    Set FileNameRange = Range("A2:A21")


    For Each actCell In FileNameRange
        'Debug.Print actCell.Address
        ActFileName = actCell.Value
        SelFolder = actCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Select Case SelFolder
            Case 0
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder0)
            Case 1
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder1)
            Case 2
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder2)
            Case 3
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder3)
            Case 4
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder4)
        End Select
    Next actCell


End Sub

'Sub Save2Folder() '(locFileName As String, FolderStr As String)
Sub Save2Folder(locFileName, FolderStr)
    Dim Po15k As String 'Path to the 15k Files
    Po15k = "/Volumes/G-DRIVE\ mobile\ USB-C/resortTrainFirst24 "

    FileCopy Po15k & locFileName & ".jpg", FolderStr & locFileName & ".jpg"
End Sub
```

But got the error "Path not found" Any suggestions?

Comment: You might need a / or \ after "... resortTrainFirst24 ": `Po15k = "/Volumes/G-DRIVE\ mobile\ USB-C/resortTrainFirst24\"`. Also Folder0 to Folder4 need a slash or backslash at the end of the string!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Dim iRow

Sub InitSampleData()
    Range("B1") = "10_left"
    Range("B2") = "10_right"
    Range("B3") = "13_left"
    Range("B4") = "13_right"
    Range("B5") = "13_left"
    Range("B6") = "13_right"

    Range("C1") = 0
    Range("C2") = 0
    Range("C3") = 1
    Range("C4") = 1
    Range("C5") = 2
    Range("C6") = 4
End Sub

Sub SaveFilesToFolders()

Dim Folder0 As String, Folder1 As String, Folder2 As String, Folder3 As String, Folder4 As String
Dim FileNameRange As Range
Dim actCell As Range
Dim SelFolder As Integer
Dim ActFileName As String

    Folder0 = "C:\temp\xxx\MySpecialFolder0\"
    Folder1 = "C:\temp\xxx\MySpecialFolder1\"
    Folder2 = "C:\temp\xxx\MySpecialFolder2\"
    Folder3 = "C:\temp\xxx\MySpecialFolder3\"
    Folder4 = "C:\temp\xxx\MySpecialFolder4\"

    'Set FileNameRange = Range("B2:B15001")
    Set FileNameRange = Range("B1:B6")

    For Each actCell In FileNameRange
        'Debug.Print actCell.Address
        ActFileName = actCell.Value
        SelFolder = actCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Select Case SelFolder
            Case 0
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder0)
            Case 1
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder1)
            Case 2
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder2)
            Case 3
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder3)
            Case 4
                Call Save2Folder(ActFileName, Folder4)
        End Select
    Next actCell


End Sub

'Sub Save2Folder() '(locFileName As String, FolderStr As String)
Sub Save2Folder(locFileName, FolderStr)
    Dim Po15k As String 'Path to the 15k Files
    'Po15k = "C:\MyFolderWith15000Files\"
    Po15k = "C:\temp\xxx\"
    FileCopy Po15k & locFileName & ".jpg", FolderStr & locFileName & ".jpg"
End Sub

'With the below routines you can get a listing of your 15000 files.
'Or you can check the destination folders.
'You need to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" via IBE Menu "Tools - References"

Sub ListFiles()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = "ListOf_15000_Files"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Call ListMyFiles("C:\MyFolderWith15000Files\", IncludeSubfolders:=False)
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders)
Dim MyObject, mySource, myFile, mySubFolder
Dim iCol As Integer, iRow As Integer

    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        iCol = 2
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Name
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried on a smaller test it but got the error "path not found", please check my implementation above. Thank you so much!